# missing page dbpedia sparql

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I installed a version of Live DBpedia on a local instance, using the latest dump (`dbpedia_2015_06_02.nt.gz`).

When I query for `person`s using the following query, for example:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?Concept WHERE {?Concept a foaf:Person}
```

I get a list of results, but not all of them are working on my local instance. For instance, `http://dbpedia.org/resource/Ivan_Rabuzin`. If I use `{my local host}/resource/Ivan_Rabuzin`, I get an "empty" page ("No further information is available. (The requested entity is unknown)"), while `http://live.dbpedia.org/resource/Ivan_Rabuzin` returns a valid page.

Why does a page show up in my query, but not when I browse it?

Also (may be related): I see around 3.9M "things" in my database, while Live DBPedia has 4.2M. Does this make sense?  0.3M added in ~2 months?

Comment: What happens if you go to `{your local host}/sparql/` and run the query `DESCRIBE <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Ivan_Rabuzin>`?

Answer (score 0):

Stack Overflow is focused on programming questions, which this does not appear to be.

`live.dbpedia.org` data is constantly updated based on extractions from the Wikipedia update firehose.

`dbpedia.org` data is updated periodically, and has just this week been populated with the extractions from the April Wikipedia dump.

I suggest you raise this question on the [DBpedia discussion mailing list](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/dbpedia-discussion).